# How camera calculates amount of color per pixel

Tags: sensor, camera

I don't know where to post this question sorry if it's in wrong section.
I already know how pixels works they are combination of three colors
RED, BLUE and Green. But they should be mixed in different amounts to
create a required color, I wanna ask how camera measures the amount of single
color to be mixed for the result color.

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't calculate. It measures.

Comment: I'll just mention that this has been answered a pile of different ways on the Photography SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The camera measures the amount of light in each 'bin', red blue or green, and that is the amount of light that your monitor should emit from the red, green and blue pixels in its display in order to be perceived by your eye as that original color.

This only works because the human eye has receptors for red, green and blue light, and that's how it sees color. The spectrum is certainly not necessarily the same for the light emitted by the monitor as what was originally measured.

For example, sunlight has a spectrum that looks like this:

[image: http://www.reeftank123.com/lighting/spectrum_sunlight.jpg]

But white light from an LCD display has a spectrum that looks like this:

[image: **enter image description here**]

It's a little more complicated than that because the filter colors in the display and camera don't match the eye response exactly.

Comment: is there any example of color camera that can make me understand more?  it could be like old camera mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using a color camera to produce black and white outputs, you never combine them. Instead, the outputs of each color are handled separately, and the display screen shows separate pixels for each color.

Answer (score 1):

The camera does not measure the colour, it just measures the amount of red light, the amount of blue light and the amount of green light.

Those same numbers that go to make up the display pixel.

These days digital cameras do this by using patterned colour filters in front of their photo-receptors.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to it.

1. The dye in the camera that "converts" the light to electrons does not have a linear response over the light spectrum - see an example:
   [image]
2. So, to get a response for say three different colors/wave lengths - like red green and blue, you would need three image sensors having filters on top of them to pass only the desired wavelength. Since it is not practical, they use a filter array on a single sensor and then obtain/interpolate all three colors for each pixel using information from neighboring pixels. This does not represent the true information as it would be in the case of three sensors, but it is good enough for us:

[image]

3. There are several standards for image sensors to represent the data (which could be a new question), and the end point is to scale and display that data to match human eye perception (left), since it is different from sensor's perception (right). As @Spehro Pefhany pointed out, we can use a mix of red green and blue color intensities to "create" any color to be perceived by human eye.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In cameras, each pixel location has a "well" that accumulate energy from photons. Photon energy is converted  into small amounts of electrical charge, which we can then measure (in millivolts). To get colors, we apply filters, so that only energy with the right frequency is measured. A typical setup is the Bayer filter, where a 2 by 2 pixel area collects Red/Green/Green/Blue. This is then combined into a single RGB pixel in a post process called de-Bayering.